# #include in C# (conditional compilation)

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

Is it possible in C# to set such a condition that if the condition is true - compile one file; if the condition is false - compile another file?

Sort of like

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#include Class1.cs
#else
#include Class2.cs
#endif
```

Or possibly set it up in project properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't.

However, you can wrap both entire files in `#if` blocks.

You might also want to look at the [`[Conditional]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx).

Comment: Also don't forget that partial classes and partial methods can be extremely useful in cases like that.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend it. I don't like the idea of Debug and Release having such wildly different code that you need to have two totally separate files to make sense of the differences. `#if DEBUG` *at all* is a pretty big code smell IMO...

However, you *could* do it like this:

```
// Class1.cs
#if DEBUG

...

#endif
```

.

```
// Class2.cs
#if !DEBUG

...

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# we don't use an include of a file, but you can use conditional methods.

For instance, if I'm developing a game and I'm using a shared code base for my input class, but I want to have one method called if I'm on an [Xbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox), and a different method get called if I'm on a [Zune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zune). It's still going to return the same class of input data, but it's going to take a very different route to get it.

You learn more about conditional methods here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: The link is half-broken (*"Visual Studio 2003 Retired Technical documentation"*).

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully no, not in the preprocessor like that. You can, however, exclude the implementation of a whole file within the file itself. Or you can set up a build process with MSBuild or [NAnt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt) to switch around our files.